# Problems hiding google maps marker onClick event

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have put some markers for specific locations in a map, and I have two buttons, one to hide all the markers (`clearOverlays`) and other to show them again (`showOverlays`) but it isn't working. In my JavaScript console I am getting this error : `Cannot call method 'setMap' of undefined`

Here's my code..

```
// COORDENADAS
var coordenadas = [
  ['Punto 1',   19.558061,-99.296344, 4],
  ['Punto 2',  19.55886, -99.296886,  5],
  ['Punto 3',19.559103, -99.296688,  3],
  ['Punto 4',   19.560164,-99.297347, 2],
  ['Punto 5',19.560073,-99.296064, 1]
];


 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 16,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng( 19.561883, -99.298287),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});


var ventana = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marcador, i;

for (i = 0; i < coordenadas.length; i++) {  
        marcador = new google.maps.Marker
        ({

          position: new google.maps.LatLng(coordenadas[i][1], coordenadas[i][2]),
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          map: map

        });


        google.maps.event.addListener(
                marcador, 'mouseover', (function(marcador, i) {
                    return function() {
                      ventana.setContent(coordenadas[i][0]);
                      ventana.open(map, marcador);
                    }
                })(marcador, i)
        );

  }


function clearOverlays(map) {
  for (var i = 0; i < coordenadas.length; i++) {
    marcador[i].setMap(null);
  }      
  setAllMap(null);
  console.log('click Ocultar');
}

function showOverlays(map) {
  for (var i = 0; i < coordenadas.length; i++) {
    marcador[i].setMap(map);
  }      
  setAllMap(map);
  console.log('click Mostar');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

marcador is not an array.  marcador[i] doesn't exist.  That gives the error message: `Cannot call method 'setMap' of undefined`

You need an array of google.maps.Marker objects.

```
var gmarkers = [];

function clearOverlays(map) {
  for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
    gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
  }      
}

function showOverlays(map) {
  for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
    gmarkers[i].setMap(map);
  }      
}  

for (i = 0; i < coordenadas.length; i++) {  
        var marcador = new google.maps.Marker
        ({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(coordenadas[i][1], coordenadas[i][2]),
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          map: map

        });
        gmarkers.push(marcador);

        google.maps.event.addListener(
                marcador, 'mouseover', (function(marcador, i) {
                    return function() {
                      ventana.setContent(coordenadas[i][0]);
                      ventana.open(map, marcador);
                    }
                })(marcador, i)
        );
  }
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_showHideMarkers.html)

Comment: ooohhhh i see, thank you very much,for the help and for answer so fast.

But i have a question, i see that you separete the code, one part is the array i used with lat and ln points, you add  the function clear and show overlays and a new arrar named gmarkes that is the arrray of google maps object you said, but i dont get it, how this wokrs because gmarkers look like an indepent array, i dont see the relation for saying in some way, i see you used the argument "map" and i have a var named map in the secon block of code.

Regards

Comment: You need to call setMap on a google.maps.Marker object.  gmarkers is an array of google.maps.Marker objects.  In your original code, marcador was a reference to the last google.maps.Marker created